# Async Programming in C# Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am using the Repository pattern in my Solution. In the generic repository common methods (Add, Update and Get) all use the Async methods.

I also have separate Application layer as well as a presentation layer which currently holds an MVC project.

My question is, is it enough to have the repository pattern use async methods? Or should I also immplement my application interfaces use async as well as my MVC controllers being async methods?

I am quite confused about the subject so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you will need "async all the way"

Comment: Any method which invokes an `async` operation should itself *be* an `async` operation.  (Unless one has *very* good reason not to and one *really* understands what's happening under the hood and is prepared to account for it...)

Comment: @David thank you.. Could open the part where you say "what's happening under the hood and is prepared to account for it"?

Comment: @SubliminalHash: For all reasonable intents and purposes, you won't need to worry about it.  Just make use of `async` and `await` keywords and your methods will organically become `async` "all the way down".  But if you really want to dive deeper, start with a Google search for something like "c# async in depth" and start reading/tinkering.  There are entire books on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

To create an asynchronous API, you need to make all the methods from start to end asynchronous. Asynchronous is actually beneficial for I/O bound operations, such as working with files and networks. Why? Because I/O operations are handled by CPU and no threads, so during this period, calling an I/O API, and finishing the I/O operation the thread is Idel. When the operation is finished, the thread does the other steps left.
When using a method asynchronously, you actually free a thread and let the other requests coming to the application be served faster, in this case when I/O operation has finished another thread or the same does the rest, as a result, you boost throughput in your application.
This journey actually starts from a web server such as IIS or NgInit.

IIS for instance has a default of 5000 threads to serve requests that hit the server. When your API is synchronous, each request that hits the server, IIS assigns a thread to it, and that thread is in charge of getting the result from your API, if the method is synchronous, and uses an I/O operation, then the thread is busy until the end of the operation when another request hits the server, IIS assigns another thread from the thread pool to the request, so if it is continued IIS won't have any free thread so its starts queuing requests until there's is a free thread to process the request after a while IIS won't have even enough space to queue request so the server won't get any request anymore. This is where asynchronous APIs come to the rescue. They help to free threads in IO operations, then IIS can serve more requests